# Brightness level starts at maximum on every boot

Tags: brightness

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to save my brightness level, because every time I start the computer the brightness level is at maximum.

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/backlight
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mai 4 06:50 acpi_video0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mai 4 06:50 intel_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight
```

Comment: The best say to do this is probably via /sys and ACPI scripts to manage the values, however in order to design a solution tailored to you, we will need more information. Please provide the output of `ls -l /sys/class/backlight` for starters.

Comment: kolyo@kolyo-ThinkPad-Edge-E540:~$ ls -l /sys/class/backlight
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mai  4 06:50 acpi_video0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mai  4 06:50 intel_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight
kolyo@kolyo-ThinkPad-Edge-E540:~$

Comment: `ls -l /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0` (please edit your question with this information)

Answer (score 1):

To find out current brightness

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

To change brightness

```
echo [brightness value] > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

To change brightness permanently

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
```

add the following line above 'exit 0' at the bottom of document

```
echo [brightness value] > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

replace `[brightness value]` with the correct value determined by experiment - more than 0 and less than whatever is in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness` or the corresponding file.

If `echo foo > /sys/class/bar...` etc throws a permission error in the shell, try

```
echo foo | sudo tee /sys/class/bar...
```

If that doesn't work, you can't change that access point. There's no need for `sudo tee` in `/etc/rc.local` though.